# Formulation de « vivement » avec un moment précis pour marquer le souhait ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, adverbes, interjections

En cherchant une réponse à une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52401/26366), j'ai remarqué qu'on trouve parfois « vivement le [date/jour/saison/point culminant d'une activité] » après « j'y serai » :

> J'y serai ! **Vivement** le 14 février !

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivement) dit que c'est familier pour « exprimer le souhait qu'un événement se produise au plus tôt » (aussi avec *que* et le subjonctif).

- Serait-il usuel d'avoir une formulation comme « vivement que j'y
  serai ! » ou « j'y serai(,) vivement ! » ?
- Au lieu de l'article défini, serait-il usuel d'avoir une formulation avec le possessif (« vivement
  sa fête !») ou le démonstratif (« vivement cette fête !») ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Non, à ma connaissance les formes « vivement que » suivi de l'indicatif ne sont pas utilisées ; les formes du type « j'y serai(,) vivement ! » ne le sont pas non plus.
2. On ne trouve pas l'usage avec un possessif dans les livres (un seul cas pour « sa », « son », et « leur »), mais je ne vois pas ce qui empêche de s'en servir.

> [Le Royaume de Pierre d'angle (tome 4): Courage -2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Royaume_de_Pierre_d_angle_tome_4/0nAUEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22vivement+son%22&pg=PT678&printsec=frontcover))  Au grand soulagement de lancelot, il sauta alors sur son cheval et se lança au galop. Vivement les attributs. Vivement qu'on en finisse. Parlant d'intérêt personnel, il avait besoin d'un bon cognac, puis d'un bon repos. Vivement son lit. Il boirait le cognac sous le grand baldaquin rouge, il dormirait comme un loir, puis, dès le réveil il programmerait son excursion à tête reposée.

Par exemple, une phrase comme la suivante me parait correcte.

- Vivement leur retour, qu'on ait du personnel sur qui pouvoir compter.

3. Pour ce qui est du démonstratif il semble n'exister aucun cas (un seul pour « ce »).

> [Maryse Hanriot-Colin · 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vivement_ce_soir_qu_on_se_couche/ZwvMDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22vivement+ce%22&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover) Vivement ce soir qu'on se couche

Il n'y a pas de raison de ne pas dire « vivement cet après-midi », tout aussi bien. D'autres possibilités semblent naturelles, en particulier lorsqu'une complémentation accompagne le nom.

- Vivement ce départ dramatique qu'il nous a promis ! Je ne peux plus le supporter…